# Service for accepting short video clips as part of official documents?

Tags: video

I am looking for a service that can accept short video clips flexibly and convert to an archival format. So the process would be:

- Person in the field uploads a video by:

  1. Smartphone upload
  2. Upload from camera via laptop
  3. Upload from browser via Flash
- Service normalizes the video to some standard format (AVI? with standard quality)
- Service generates a thumbnail and embeds in a larger report
- Thumbnail is clickable to get the larger video

These are private, assessment videos, so they need to be confidential. Most of the online services out there (YouTube, Vimeo, etc) do parts of these, but don't have a commercial or archival component. Ideally the service would have an API, but if it satisfies the bullet points above a "self-serve" YouTube quality would be great.

I did searching and mostly I've found components limited by browser (ActiveX controls and such) or not allowed to be private.

I'd prefer to buy a service rather than reinvent this wheel. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a service, or are self-installed applications an option? Also, could you explain the second point some more? For example, if the videos are going to be viewed on-site, who cares about standardizing the formats in the back end, as long as they're just viewable? Transcoding is expensive and seems possibly pointless here.

Comment: Self installed applications are an option, yes. The need for an archival version is that at times these documents may be needed to either a) provide to a customer or b) be provided as a legal document in support of an assessment.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements go into some things I haven't had to examine, but you might check out [MediaCore](http://mediacore.com/). The [underlying software is open source](http://mediacorecommunity.org/) if you're also considering self-hosting.

[Cumulus](http://cumulusclips.org/) is another "video platform" application, but self-hosted only. It's also a younger project, so may not have all the capabilities you need.

Comment: MediaCore seems good, though both it ans Cumulus really seem to be geared toward "roll your own YouTube" - which is not really what I'm looking for, but it may be what I settle for. Thanks.